# JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property '1' of undefined or null reference

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

I am trying to select the data from a cell in kendo grid using the row index and column index when clicking on the link from the same grid. The following is the code I have used.

```
$('#AssetsGrid').on('click', '.statusLink', function () {   
var grid = $('#AssetsGrid').data().kendoGrid;  
var value = grid.Rows[2].Cells[1].Value;  
alert(value);  
});
```

I am getting the following error when clicking on that link.

**JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property '2' of undefined or null reference**

Please help me with the issue.

Comment: Please provide html also. And if you can provide all three files (html, css , js)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your `alert(value)` with `debug`.
Open your browser's Developer Tools, so that you have a javascript console.
When your code hits debug, and you can type in the console, type:

```
grid
```

You may find that it has a property called `rows`, not `Rows`. But I think that you want:

```
grid[2][1]
```

instead of `grid.Rows[2].Cells[1]`